# How to write data in a subcollection? Firebase React

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wish to be able to add projects in a subcollection called projects. Currently my tree is: db/membres/[membreID]/projects/(here I want project ID that firebase generates)/(information of project)
Here is my firebase:
[image]

here's what i've tried:
[image]

This is the error I get: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but membres/UVLPL9kxP1hGuiwCStS4oDLJvxo1/projets has 3.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear: you are trying to write to a document at path `/membres/$uid/projects`, but that is the path of a collection.

If you want to add a document to that subcollection, use `addDoc` instead of `setDoc`.

Answer (score 0):

addDoc works like that:

```
addDoc(CollectionReference //i.e collection(db, "path"), element)
```